# Из-за чего появляется проблема abort() has been called?

Tags: c++, openssl, poco

Установлены библиотеки OpenSSL 3.0.3 от 3 мая 2022 года.
Скомпилированы библиотеки Poco Project 1.11.3

при выполнении строки
`Poco::Crypto::CipherKey key("aes-256", passwordKey, saltKey);` программа вылетает с ошибкой как на скрине
[image: ошибка]
более подробно ничего выяснить не выходит, так же ничего конкретного не могу найти по проблеме

Код:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>  
#include "Poco/Environment.h"  
#include <string>  
#include <Poco/Crypto/CipherKey.h>  
#include <Poco/Crypto/Cipher.h>  
#include <Poco/Crypto/CipherFactory.h>  

std::string encryptAES256(std::string& text, std::string& password, std::string& salt)  
{   
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ByteVec saltKey{ salt.begin(), salt.end() };  
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ByteVec passwordKey{ password.begin(), password.end() };  
    Poco::Crypto::CipherKey key("aes-256", passwordKey, saltKey);  
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Ptr cipher = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory().createCipher(key);  
    return cipher->encryptString(text, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ENC_BASE64);  
}  

std::string decryptAES256(std::string& text, std::string& password, std::string& salt)  
{  
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ByteVec saltKey{ salt.begin(), salt.end() };  
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ByteVec passwordKey{ password.begin(), password.end() };  
    Poco::Crypto::CipherKey key("aes-256", passwordKey, saltKey);  
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Ptr pCipherAES256 = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory().createCipher(key);  
    return pCipherAES256->decryptString(text, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ENC_BASE64);  
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    std::ofstream fout("output.txt");  
    std::string buffer = "OS Name: " + Poco::Environment::osName() + '\n';  
    std::string key = Poco::Environment::nodeName();  
    std::string salt = Poco::Environment::nodeId();  
    buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);  
    fout << buffer;  

    buffer = "OS Version: " + Poco::Environment::osVersion() + '\n';  
    buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);  
    fout << buffer;  
    buffer = "OS Arch: " + Poco::Environment::osArchitecture() + '\n';  
    buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);  
    fout << buffer;  
    
    buffer = "Node Name: " + Poco::Environment::nodeName() + '\n';
    buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);
    fout << buffer;

    buffer = "Node ID: " + Poco::Environment::nodeId() + '\n';
    buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);
    fout << buffer;

    if (Poco::Environment::has("HOME"))
    {
        buffer = "Home: " + Poco::Environment::get("HOME") + '\n';
        std::string key = Poco::Environment::nodeName();
        buffer = encryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);
        fout << buffer;;
    }

    fout.close();
    std::ifstream fin("output.txt");
    fin >> buffer;
    buffer = decryptAES256(buffer, key, salt);
    std::cout << buffer;


    Poco::Environment::set("POCO", "foo");
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

дебаг показывает на библиотеку OpenSSLInitializer.h,

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x30000000L  
        if (!_defaultProvider)  
        {  
            _defaultProvider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "default");  
            if (!_defaultProvider) throw CryptoException("Failed to load OpenSSL default provider");  
        }  
        if (!_legacyProvider)  
        {  
            _legacyProvider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "legacy");  
            if (!_legacyProvider) throw CryptoException("Failed to load OpenSSL legacy provider");  
        }  
#endif   
    }
```

[image: ош9ибка в библиотеке]

Comment: В окошке следует нажать Retry и отладить программу.

Comment: он ссылается на библиотеку OpenSSLInitializer.h

Comment: Вот приводите то место, где это происходит и стек вызовов.

Comment: Что-то не сходится, в первом случае показывает, что сработал `abort`, а во втором - что выкинуто исключение.